# Workaround for accessing non-static members inside static member functions

Tags: c++, class, static

What are the workarounds for accessing the non-static member variables of some class(Say A) inside static member functions of another class(Say B)? I am coding in c++. Class A is derived with public properties of class B.

Any pointers?

Comment: A non-static member is accesed via the object, a static member via the class. So to access the non-static member from a static member function, you will need to know the object for which you want to acess the member var. Can you say something more about your problem?

Comment: If you need this, you probably have bad design or don't understand the purpose of static and non-static members (or it's an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)). Can you be more specific about why you (think you) need this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a reference/pointer to the instance when calling the static member function. Use that instance to call the non-static member function.

Answer (score 0):

Non static members are accessible through the instances of the class. So you can access the members(nonstatic) through instance of that class in static member functions.

Regards,
Spk